# Sitecore - "Clean" package installation for RTE button

Tags: sitecore, rich-text-editor

I am creating a Sitecore module which includes a new button within the Rich Text Editor.

In order to register the command for the button I had to append some code to the `RichText Commands.js` file.

I had hoped that I could create the installation package in such a way that it would be simple, without any additional manual intervention required.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Is there any way I can the add the javascript command registration code without amending an existing file?
2. Is there somewhere in the Sitecore tree I can put the button so it appears for all RTE profiles? - a sort of "global profile".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your own client scripts by adding an entry into the config. Patch the following:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">  
  <sitecore>  
    <clientscripts>  
      <htmleditor>  
        <script src="/sitecore modules/shell/Controls/Rich Text Editor/Custom RichText Commands.js" language="JavaScript"/>  
      </htmleditor>  
    </clientscripts>  
  </sitecore>  
</configuration>
```

Here is a [detailed blog post](http://sitecoreblog.blogspot.ca/2012/10/add-custom-button-in-rich-text-editor.html) about it.

There is no setting that I know of so that all profiles display the button. You have to add it to the profiles you wish the button to show on. Either:

- add it to the default profile
- make a copy of an existing profile, rename it to `Rich Text Default` and add/remove whatever you want
- Change `<setting name="HtmlEditor.DefaultProfile" value="/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Default"/>` in web.config to your custom profile

If you set the DataSource of a rich text field to a different one then obviously the default settings will not take effect.